Xcode unexpected error after adding a notification extension service
I'm working on a React Native mobile app, we use firebase services ( FCM ) for notifications and expo for deployment. I'm currently working on notifications, the code is ok, I receive the notifications correctly on android with the image in the notification ( body, title and image ) but on the ios device, I do not receive the image in the notication, only the text.
So I found that I need to add a notification extension service in Xcode to receive image in notifications for ios.
I followed the rnfirebase documentation ( https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/ios-notification-images ) this is pretty simple to follow but the thing is that my app wont build after thoses 3 steps. I only have the following error: "Unexepected failure" on my ImageNotification service extension as you can see on the following screenshot.
Error
I tried a lot of differents things the last 2 days but nothing seems to work. I deleted and did everything from a working build 3 times but it does not work and I don't get why.
